# Returning vectors that use custom allocators

Tags: c++, vector, stl, allocator

Suppose you developed an optimized **custom allocator** that you want to use with `std::vector` (for example, for small allocations the custom allocator gets memory from the stack instead of the heap, kind of like `std::string`'s SSO; or it allocates big chunks of memory using e.g. `VirtualAlloc` on Windows, and then single allocations are carved from inside a chunk just increasing a pointer).

```
typedef std::vector<T, OptimizedAllocator<T>> OptimizedVector;
```

How to use it in a context where you are returning a vector from a function, like this?

```
OptimizedVector DoSomething() 
{
    OptimizedVector<int>::allocator_type alloc{};
    OptimizedVector<int> v{alloc};

    // Do stuff...

    return v;
}
```

At the end of the function's scope, the allocator object is destroyed, so the returned vector could contain garbage, right?

An alternative might be to pass the allocator object as a reference to each function as an additional parameter, but that's kind of ugly...

Is there a way to safely *"embed"* the allocator object in the vector?

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: The allocator object is copied or moved to the return value. In the shown example the return value would be move constructed. Allocators need to support copying and moving.

Comment: Note: you can't safely allocated from the stack for a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes you can: https://github.com/orlp/libop/blob/master/bits/memory.h#L45.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: If the `vector` takes its memory from a custom allocator, and the custom allocator has an e.g. `T smallBuffer[10];` data member for small allocations (<= 10 items), what's wrong with that?

Comment: @orlp: No, you can't, in general, in any practically meaningful way. I can think of impractical ways, like e.g. a `const` vector using a preallocated just right size buffer. Or preallocating a large enough heap area from the stack. That's about the same as saying you can travel to the moon. Yes, in theory.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I just showed you a way it can be done. And this isn't useless - you can use that allocator to allocate on the stack for, say, the first 100 elements and if your vector grows larger than that you start using `new`. Also don't forget embedded applications that want to use `vector` without a heap.

Comment: @Mr.C64: Well, you can't have a larger vector, and you risk running out of memory even for smaller sizes, and you can't return a copy of that vector (it would reference no longer valid stack area). And so on.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: So, if I want a `vector` with an optimization similar to the `std::string` SSO, the only option I have is to write my own `OptimizedVector<T>` class template from scratch? Allocators cannot be used in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.C64: `std::basic_string` can use the small buffer optimization, which is maybe what you mean by SSO (small string optimization?). `std::vector` can't use this optimization: its interface (swapping of vectors, invalidation of references) doesn't allow it. So yes, you would have to make your own.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, SSO = Small String Optimization.

Answer (score 4):

An allocator must be CopyConstructible without exceptions, and afterwards `a1 == a2` must hold (meaning they share the same memory pool). I strongly suggest reading [this page on the Allocator concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).

`std::vector` stores a copy of the allocator you give it.

So if you properly implement your allocator to be safe to copy, there will be no problem with your given code.

Comment: that would be a problem if the allocator holds a chunk of memory as attempting to copy it could easily bad_alloc?

Comment: @CashCow An allocator must solve this problem by sharing references to the same memory pool between copies. The standard requires this behavior.

Comment: Yes, so obviously the OP must write his OptimizedAllocator to do it this way. The downside though is that if you copy an allocator across threads, they both use a shared memory resource.

Comment: If you want to implement an optimized pool allocator (e.g. calling VirtualAlloc for allocating big chunks and serving single allocations increasing a pointer inside a chunk), this pool allocator should be shared between different vector instances right? What does it mean "copying" the allocator in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The allocator is kept by copy as defined by the standard:

> n4140 §23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]/8
>
> Unless otherwise specified, all containers defined in this clause
>   obtain memory using an allocator [...] A copy of this allocator is
>   used for any memory allocation performed [...]

`vector` is not "otherwise specified".

This also means that your allocator should support copying and probably be a handle for the real allocator if it needs state.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/):

> The container keeps an internal copy of alloc, which is used to allocate and deallocate storage for its elements, and to construct and destroy them (as specified by its allocator_traits).

So, if I'm not wrong, what you're asking for is the default.